# Killing COM object from C#

Tags: c#

I have a COM object that we are calling from C#. This works great, and I have my own pool of objects that I can use whenever I want. Now I need to kill the object. I've tried releasing the COM object explicitly and then garbage collecting from another thread, but that does nothing. Does anyone have any other ideas to kill this object? Thanks for the help.

I've tried

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(myApp); 
GC.Collect(); 
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers ();
myApp = null;
```

and I create it by

```
myApplication.ApplicationClass myApp = new myApplication.ApplicationClass();
```

this is the full code
this com object is written in vb6, below is the C# code calling vb6 component

```
      myApplication.ApplicationClass myApp = new myApplication.ApplicationClass();

        string user = this._User;
        string pass = this._Pass;
        string company = this.companyNumber;

        try
        {
            if (myApp.Login(ref user, ref pass, ref company))
```

{
 //Perform some action
}
else
                    {
                    throw new System.Exception(MESSAGE_LOGINERROR);
 }
}
Finally
{
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(myApp);

```
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            M2MApp = null;
```

}

Thanks,
Pradeep

Comment: What library `ApplicationClass` is from? Is it a microsoft excel/word instance wrapped underneath?

Comment: it is not a excel or word component it is a active x dll created by me.

Comment: Post the VB6 code that accesses VFP database. It could be your VB6 code that locks up the DB & not the problem from .net end.

Comment: why are you sending ref-pointers into your myApp.Login() - function ?
Can that be your backward-reference ?

Answer (score 2):

maybe just swapping two lines, because myApp IS your reference to your object:
or try repeating until zero:

```
while (System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(myApp)>0)
       ;
myApp = null;
GC.Collect(); 
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers ();
```

Comment: sorry to hear, I always get rid of those objects via ReleaseComObject.
btw, do you call 'ReleaseComObject', until it returns zero ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, you don't have any other variable referring (holding a reference) to `myApp`.

Alternatively, a call to [`FinalReleaseComObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.finalreleasecomobject.aspx) could also be of help.
**Note**: I looked at the docs & suggesting this as an alternative. Use your discretion when making a call to this method.

Comment: There is no variable referring to the myApp

Comment: Please post full code (if you can) or a sample app for one to figure out, why is it that the COM instance is not released? what does the COM object refer to? what type it is (written in vb6/vc++/delphi)?

Comment: @Pradeep: How do you ascertain that the COM class instance is not getting released?

Comment: there is one more application using the same com object. when i perform and finish with c# operation, i am unable to open the other application which has same com reference. it will be locked.

Comment: i can open other application before perform operation in c# code, once c# code operation done i am unable to open it. after closing the complete VS project opened, only then able to open other application. in real world user want to use want to use other application after the myapp operation either they have to kill the worker process or restart iis.

Comment: what does the VB6 class do, for it to be unusable after it is used once? what do you mean by "unable to open the other application which has same com reference. it will be locked."?

Comment: the com class access visualfoxpro DB, once it finishes its transaction other application cannot open the DB, it will be locked.

Comment: Post the VB6 code that accesses VFP database. It could be your VB6 code that locks up the DB & not the problem from .net end.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem in the past and attempted all the things you've mentioned, but was unable to resolve it. Eventually I had to forcefully terminate my process to kill the COM object.

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to completely release the COM object you need to load it in a separate [AppDomain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.aspx) which you can unload after you have called `ReleaseComObject()` and done other proper cleanup for your object.

This has proved to be the only reliable way for me in the past.